# Obj-c - Crash when passing data to detailview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm passing data from my ViewController to a detailViewController with the below code, however no matter what I seem to do, my app crashes at the line

`self.username.text = self.mapuserData[@"users_name"];`

with the following error (even though data is present in `self.mapuserData`)? Help!

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI
>   objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x17126b840'

**ViewController.m**

```
  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
    {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(calloutTapped:)];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }

 -(void)calloutTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
        {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

            OtherUserViewController *yourViewController = (OtherUserViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUserViewController"];

           NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self.addressData mutableCopy];
        yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary; // this is how you do it

           [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

        }
```

**OtherViewController.m (detailview)**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self.mapuserData count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"This is map user data %@", self.mapuserData);

        self.addFriend.hidden = NO;

      self.username.text = self.mapuserData[@"users_name"];

       self.userBio.text = self.mapuserData[@"userbio"];

       NSString *thirdLink = self.mapuserData[@"photo_path"];

      NSString *ImageURLTwo = thirdLink;
       NSData *imageDataTwo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURLTwo]];

        self.userPhoto.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageDataTwo];


    }

}
```

**Here's what's in self.mapuserData:**

```
This is map user data ( 
{ 
address = "2957 fake street"; 
childrenunder = Yes; 
city = Vancouver; 
"emergency facility" = None; 
"first name" = josh; 
"last name" = tree; 
phone = 6046710890; 
"photo_path" = "http://url.ca/paw.png"; 
"points balance" = 24; 
"postal code" = b6b6v5; 
"profile photo" = "<null>"; 
"property type" = Apartment; 
province = bc; 
"special skills" = "Medication"; 
"star rating" = 0; 
"street_address" = none; 
supervision = Yes; 
uid = 182; 
userbio = nfkkdkckmfkekxkx; 
"users_name" = "josh_tree@hotmail.com";
```

Comment: `self.addressData` is array not dictionary can you show where you are setting this `calloutTapped` gesture method to any view ?

Comment: @NiravD See edit above

Comment: I remember that you have came up with similar issue before. Before you go, make sure that What kind of Datas you have. Pay some attention to your codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own class to store index of the Annotation data source. Which is subclass of `MKPointAnnotation`

**PointAnnotation.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface PointAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation

@property (nonatomic, assign)int index;

@end
```

**PointAnnotation.m**

```
#import "PointAnnotation.h"

@implementation PointAnnotation

@end
```

**Change your Add Annotation code like below**

```
    int index = 0;   //Index to track the data source index while select the annotation call out view.

    for (NSMutableDictionary *multiplelocations in self.addressData) {

        NSString *location = multiplelocations[@"street_address"];
        NSLog(@"Pull addresses %@", location);
        NSString *userNames = multiplelocations[@"users_name"];
        NSString *userBio = multiplelocations[@"userbio"];


        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
                     completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                         if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                             CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                             MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                             MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;

                             region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                             region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;


                             PointAnnotation *point = [[PointAnnotation alloc] init];
                             point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
                             point.title = userNames;
                             point.subtitle = userBio;
                             point.index = index;  // Store index here.

                             [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
                         }
                     }
         ];
        index = index + 1;
    }
```

And modify your `didSelectAnnotationView` code like below

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

        //Get the annotation object from callout view.
        PointAnnotation *selectedPoint = (PointAnnotation *) view.annotation;

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        OtherUserViewController *yourViewController = (OtherUserViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUserViewController"];

        //Get the dictionary from array by using the index of the custom        PointAnnoation object.
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = self.addressData[selectedPoint.index];
        yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary; 

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

You are assigning an `Array` to `Dictionary` which is wrong.

```
   NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self.addressData mutableCopy];
        yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary;
```

Comment: Implementing the above now! Re: array to dictionary being wrong, so do I remove those last lines, or leave them in with your above edits?

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary you are expecting is the array type at the run time so you need  change the code above

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self.addressData[0] mutableCopy];
```

change  `addressData` to `NSArray`

Comment: Ok this doesn't crash my app, however it makes every selection I tap turn return detailView with all same data? Lol or rather, detailView always has the data of the first object?

Comment: you can use `lastObject` or give the Index as per your use , i can't understand , what it is everytime so i had writtent  index as 0  ,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

`self.mapuserData` is no more deserializes into dictionary, It is deserializes into array.

So what you want to do is:

Get an object from zero index form `self.mapuserData` and then save as dictionary.

Example : `NSDictionary *dict = self.mapuserData[0];`

self.mapuserData should be type of array.

Comment: How do I just change self.mapuserData to type array?

Comment: Nice question! Here is my code

`NSMutableArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];`